# Best way to test and deploy aws lambda functions in a step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-step-functions

Long time stack overflow lurker and fist time poster.

I've started a new project using AWS lambdas and have found the learning curve particularly steep coming from a background of developing desktop applications.

When developing desktop applications it's easy to create a test environment locally. I know it's possible to test lambda functions locally and I've been able to do this for simple cases.

The lambda functions I'm using interact a lot with other AWS services (S3, Aurora, etc). Also, the final solution will include around 15 lambda functions linked via a step function.

I want to know if it's possible to create a separate test environment to the live production environment for the entire step function. This would allow me to perform system tests before deploying to production.

I've looked into AWS codepipeline as a possible solution but I'm not sure if this would allow me to create a seperate test environment before deploying to production.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to have separate AWS accounts, one for dev and one for prod?

Comment: That is an excellent idea. Thanks!